# ROS large map solutions

Tags: memory, ros

I'm working on path finding in a large map. I'm using the costmap_2d package with a four-layer costmap(static_map, obstables, inflation and a self-defined layer).

I ran into a problem that the costmap is too large to be held in memory. (Since the costmap is initialised with "costmap_ = new unsigned char[size_x * size_y];", and each layer will have a copy of the costmap).

I want to know what are the options I have in ROS context, and any other useful suggestions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if You are using all layers with parameter `static_map: true`, you can't do much to optimize space. but if you use `rolling_window` instead you can set your layers to have smaller size (the amount you need to determine path in local scene) with higher frequency.

but still i suggest to keep Global costmap on static_map.